# Chef bootstrap failing to talk to chef manager

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping

I am trying out Chef , where I am trying to bootstrap a node from workstation , seems like the node is bootstrapped just fine and it shows up in Chef Server nodes, but if you look at the logs below , seems like the workstation seems to fail to talk to Chef Manager , I can access the chef manager from the workstation too .

```
[2016-10-18T15:43:42-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/farazk/nodes/unode, retry 5/5
```

Here is complete output of knife

```
   test1@ubuntudesk:~/chef-repo$ knife bootstrap 192.168.131.111 -x test1 -P BatmanRobin -N unode --sudo
    Node unode exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y
    Client unode exists, overwrite it? (Y/N) Y
    Creating new client for unode
    Creating new node for unode
    Connecting to 192.168.131.111
    192.168.131.111 knife sudo password: 
    Enter your password: 
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 -----> Installing Chef Omnibus (-v 12)
    192.168.131.111 downloading https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/chef/install.sh
    192.168.131.111   to file /tmp/install.sh.6624/install.sh
    192.168.131.111 trying wget...
    192.168.131.111 ubuntu 16.04 x86_64
    192.168.131.111 Getting information for chef stable 12 for ubuntu...
    192.168.131.111 downloading https://omnitruck-direct.chef.io/stable/chef/metadata?v=12&p=ubuntu&pv=16.04&m=x86_64
    192.168.131.111   to file /tmp/install.sh.6628/metadata.txt
    192.168.131.111 trying wget...
    192.168.131.111 sha1    a2de7d933734d3a0c4b859576d0be472c5cd55f7
    192.168.131.111 sha256  7073541beb4294c994d4035a49afcf06ab45b3b3933b98a65b8059b7591df6b8
    192.168.131.111 url https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef/12.15.19/ubuntu/16.04/chef_12.15.19-1_amd64.deb
    192.168.131.111 version 12.15.19
    192.168.131.111 downloaded metadata file looks valid...
    192.168.131.111 downloading https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef/12.15.19/ubuntu/16.04/chef_12.15.19-1_amd64.deb
    192.168.131.111   to file /tmp/install.sh.6628/chef_12.15.19-1_amd64.deb
    192.168.131.111 trying wget...
    192.168.131.111 Comparing checksum with sha256sum...
    192.168.131.111 Installing chef 12
    192.168.131.111 installing with dpkg...
    192.168.131.111 Selecting previously unselected package chef.
    (Reading database ... 175392 files and directories currently installed.)
    192.168.131.111 Preparing to unpack .../chef_12.15.19-1_amd64.deb ...
    192.168.131.111 Unpacking chef (12.15.19-1) ...
    192.168.131.111 Setting up chef (12.15.19-1) ...
    192.168.131.111 Thank you for installing Chef!
    192.168.131.111 Starting the first Chef Client run...
    192.168.131.111 Starting Chef Client, version 12.15.19
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:22-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode, retry 1/5
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:27-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode, retry 2/5
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:32-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode, retry 3/5
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:37-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode, retry 4/5
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:42-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode, retry 5/5
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 ================================================================================
    192.168.131.111 Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "unode"
    192.168.131.111 ================================================================================
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 Networking Error:
    192.168.131.111 -----------------
    192.168.131.111 Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode - Failed to open TCP connection to cent7:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 Your chef_server_url may be misconfigured, or the network could be down.
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 Relevant Config Settings:
    192.168.131.111 -------------------------
    192.168.131.111 chef_server_url  "https://cent7/organizations/test1k"
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 Platform:
    192.168.131.111 ---------
    192.168.131.111 x86_64-linux
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 
    192.168.131.111 Running handlers:
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:47-07:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
    192.168.131.111 Running handlers complete
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:47-07:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
    192.168.131.111 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 27 seconds
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:47-07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:47-07:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:47-07:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://cent7/organizations/test1k/nodes/unode - Failed to open TCP connection to cent7:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
    192.168.131.111 [2016-10-18T15:43:47-07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the target node failing, not the workstation. It means the hostname `cent7` works from your workstation, but not from the server you are bootstrapping. Make sure you didn't add it to your hosts file or are using some resolver path tricks.

Comment: You mean its the node that is unable to to talk to cent7 (Chef Server) ? Since I dont have domain setup , I have added static routes in /etc/hosts so that I can reach server via hostname but not IP , Should I add the same route to the node for Chef server ?

Comment: Yes, or just use the IP address in your config so it works on all systems